# Can I retry the expert challenges?

Tags: mario-luigi-dream-team

I didn't complete the first two Dodge Ten Expert Challenges before progressing in the game. Is there a way to do them later?

What happens when I have killed all enemies in an area, can I still do the challenges?

Comment: Note that if you use a Boo Biscuit, the attacks you dodge during no-damage dodge practice count towards Dodge Ten (and the attacks you don't dodge reset the counter). It's a good way to finish the challenges without excessive walking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When all of the enemies in an area are dead, they will respawn and be there later.

The first two Dodge Ten challenges are in Pi'illo Castle and Dreamy Pi'illo castle, respectively. As long as you return to those locations (at any point in the game) and fight the enemies that are there, **it is entirely possible to complete expert challenges you missed**.

Answer (score 1):

Just leave and go back. The enemies respawn.